# Minecraft 1.8+ crashes on launch

Tags: minecraft

When Minecraft 1.8 or above is launched, it crashes immediately with the following crash log:

```
Completely ignored arguments: [--nativeLauncherVersion, 286, --nativeLauncherVersion, 307]
[19:53:27] [Client thread/INFO]: Setting user: ninjakwool
[19:53:38] [Client thread/INFO]: LWJGL Version: 2.9.4
[19:53:43] [Client thread/INFO]: Reloading ResourceManager: Default
[19:53:47] [Sound Library Loader/INFO]: Starting up SoundSystem...
[19:53:47] [Thread-5/INFO]: Initializing LWJGL OpenAL
[19:53:47] [Thread-5/INFO]: (The LWJGL binding of OpenAL.  For more information, see http://www.lwjgl.org)
[19:53:48] [Thread-5/INFO]: OpenAL initialized.
[19:53:48] [Sound Library Loader/INFO]: Sound engine started
[19:54:01] [Client thread/INFO]: Created: 1024x512 textures-atlas
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x27b93e88, pid=5192, tid=3920
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_25-b18) (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.25-b02 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ig4dev32.dll+0x3e88]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\Matthew\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\hs_err_pid5192.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
```

Could anything be done to fix this crashing issue?

Comment: `An error report file with more information is saved as:
C:\Users\Matthew\AppData\Roaming.minecraft\hs_err_pid5192.log` Is this happening on a windows pc or Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Your error report shows Windows directories in the error log, so i'm assuming you are running Minecraft under WINE.

If this is the case, you should try running Minecraft natively. To do this, you will need some form of java installed, and you will need to download the Linux/Other version of Minecraft from [here](http://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/Minecraft.jar). (Link found [here](https://minecraft.net/en/download/))

To download Oracle Java 8, run the following commands in a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt update
sudo apt install oracle-java8-installer
```

**OR** To install OpenJRE 8, run the following commands in a terminal:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre
```

Once java is installed, open a terminal, navigate to your downloaded Minecraft.jar, and run `java -jar Minecraft.jar`; this will start the Minecraft launcher.

---

If this is a crash happening under Windows, not WINE on Ubuntu, then [this](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/archive/legacy-support/1762138-ig4dev32-dll-0x374d-error-immediate-crash-after) may be able to help you. (And this question wouldn't beloong on AskUbuntu.)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem - the latest snapshot worked perfectly but 1.8.8 crashed. It seems that it requires older Java. So the solution would be, as pizzapants184 already posted to install Java 8:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre
```

And then potentially update alternatives and set 8 to default with:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```